# Connecting to same Server with different usernames

Tags: c#, wpf, ftp

I am using the following method to list the contents of a folder:

```
private void TestFtp()
{
    try
    {
        // List all of the files from FTP
        FtpWebRequest ftprequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://m3database/recover/"));

        ftprequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername1", "********");

        ftprequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        ftprequest.UsePassive = false;
        ftprequest.Proxy = null;            

        using (var resp = ftprequest.GetResponse())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

            MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I'm connecting to a single Linux server via FTP. I'm using the credentials for `myusername1` and `myusername2` to connect.

I am able to list the directory contents when using this function if I am using `myusername1` credentials, however if I use `myusername2` it comes up with the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (503) Bad sequence of commands.

**Things that I have tried:**

1. I have tried setting `ftprequest.KeepAlive = false`.
2. I have tried using all permutations of UsePassive, Proxy etc.
3. I am able to connect to both usernames using FileZilla WITH secure FTP enabled and they both work.  Without FTP enabled, neither will connect.

It is peculiar that my code will connect using `myusername1` without SSL enabled within my code.

In summary:

- `myusername1` and `myusername2` will not connect on FileZilla without secure FTP enabled.
- `myusername1` works within my C# method without `ftprequest.EnableSsl` enabled.
- `myusername2` will not work within my C# method regardless of whether `ftprequest.EnableSsl` is enabled.
- The Exception is being triggered on the line of my `using()` statement.

**Something else I just noticed, when I hover over my `ftprequest`, it shows a NotSupportedException, but this appears regardless of which set of credentials I use**

If I hover over my initial `ftprequest` when using `myusername2`, it shows an Exception thrown before my `using()`:

[image]

Comment: FtpWebRequest.ContentType is documented as always throwing a NotSupportedException, so that probably doesn't mean much.

I can only think to use WireShark to see what is happening on the wire.

Comment: main question is.. do the files transfer over successfully ?

Comment: I can list the directory contents using `myusername1`, but not `myusername2`, even though it's the same server.

Comment: Ok, I'm downloading wireshark now

Comment: My network doesn't allow me to capture the packets :(

Answer (score 0):

This might be a shot in the dark, but have you tried using a CredentialCache?

```
        System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
        System.Net.CredentialCache cc = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
        cc.Add(new Uri("ftp://m3database"), "Basic", nc);
        System.Net.FtpWebRequest ftprequest = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://m3database/recover/");
        ftprequest.Credentials = cc;
        ftprequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

         using (var resp = ftprequest.GetResponse())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

                MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
```

The credentialcache also gives you a range of authenticationtype options ("NTLM", "Digest", "Kerberos", "Negotiate"... ).

More here --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x2s2s6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> I'm connecting to a single Linux server via FTP.

CHMOD the perms on the FTP server/folder for the 2nd User, they should be the same as the 1st User.

CHMOD 777 will allow access required..